# Why flutter release apk is getting crashed?

Tags: android, flutter, release

I have an application that can be launched from VisualStudio Code; both the debug and profile versions are installed and opened correctly in my terminal, but the signed release version is giving an error when I open it.

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l11Dn.jpg)

[Manifest File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krxE0.png)

Answer (score 3):

It says there is an illegal access. Theoretically, in debug mode everything is open and every permission is granted, because it's for testing and debugging. But in release mode, you are not testing anymore, and you need to request permissions from users who uses your app. So, you can check the `AndroidManifest.xml` in `android/app/src/main` folder and set some permissions if needed (For example, you are using Google Maps and you must request location and internet permission) and edit your code based on these permissions.

Update:

In this [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58479) issue link, a user says he solved this problem like below:

I did downgrade the Gradle to 3.6.2 and it did the trick for me:

update `android/build.gradle`

replaced:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
}
```

Then run these commands on terminal:

```
flutter clean
flutter build appbundle --release
```

Maybe your Gradle version is higher, but you can try to downgrade it.

Comment: Apparently in the manifest of the main folder I don't have permissions, the last time I did a release 1 month ago everything was correct. I have added an image to the description

Comment: Flutter is being improved everytime, so they might changed some settings. Can you check the Flutter Google Maps documentation?

Comment: Yes, 
I reviewed it but did not find a solution to this bro.

Comment: Also try that and it doesn't work